# Kendo Grid Detail Init Event not firing in IE browser

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am struggling with Kendo grid Detail Init Event not firing in IE browser.
The same event is working fine with all other browsers.
I referred the example from Kendo docs.
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/detailinit

I have put the debugger and that's not hitting when I do F12 in IE browser.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image: jQuery sample code attached]

Comment: Which version of IE? Does the Kendo exmaple work in that version of IE?

Comment: It´s working on IE11